# Master/Detail flow ListView in Detail text Color is invisible

Tags: android, listview, master-detail

I have a Master/Detail View Activity generated by ADT 2.3.3 where I added a ListView on the Detail Fragment onCreateView as follows:

```
ListView myListView = (ListView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.customer_type_list);

final ArrayList<String> myFamily = new ArrayList<String>();
myFamily.add("Rob");
myFamily.add("Kirsten");
myFamily.add("Tommy");
myFamily.add("Ralphie");

ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, 
                myFamily);

myListView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
```

The list view is shown on the Detail view but all the items have the text invisible:

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Oj3i.png)

I found in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23006440/android-listview-text-color-is-invisible-and-i-dont-want-it-invisible) that this could happen if the incorrect context is send on the adapter but couldn't find the correct Context.

This is my detail layout in case is needed:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="mx.com.megcloud.placacentro.Home">

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/customer_type_list"
        android:layout_width="1008dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/linearLayout" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:context="mx.com.megcloud.placacentro.Login"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/customer_type_te"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Tipo de cliente"
            android:inputType="textPersonName" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/percentage_te"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="% de comision"
            android:inputType="number" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="%"
            android:textSize="30sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="addCustomerType"
            android:text="Agregar" />
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Hopefully you can help me.

I'm using API 25

Comment: Did you set the adapter ?

Comment: @ZeekHuge Thank you, I did. I just added the setAdapter part to my post so it's complete.

Comment: You mean that solved the problem ?

Comment: @ZeekHuge unfortunately no, I already had it on my code but forgot to copy it on the post here.

Comment: try `getActivity()` instead of `getContext()`.

Comment: I have tried `getActivity()`, `getActivity().getBaseContext()`  and even `rootView.getContext()` but none works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found the answer and it had nothing to do with the Context. I realized that the lines on the ListView were continuing to the left where they should end a few pixels before reaching the side menu.

My ListView was going below the side menu so the text seemed invisible when in reality, it was there all along.

I changed my ListView layout as follows:

```
<ListView
        android:id="@+id/customer_type_list"
        android:layout_width="1008dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent" />
```

Now is correctly align with the side menu.